# Polygon strange behavior

Tags: java-3d

I'm starting my adventure with java3d.

I'm getting unexpected results when creating my own Shape3D. I set geometry with following points (exactly in this order):

```
1 - (0.0, 0.5, 0.0), 
2 - (0.0, 0.25, 0.4330127018922193), 
3 - (0.0, -0.25, 0.43301270189221935), 
4 - (0.0, -0.5, 0.0), 
5 - (0.411819551773166, -0.25, 0.13380828366490874), 
6 - (0.4118195517731659, 0.25, 0.13380828366490874)
```

There are more, but it's enough to present the situation. If you draw/imagine it you will have points 1 and 4 in one Y line, and 2,3,5,6 creating a rectangle.

What I need to achieve is to have a plane connecting:

- Point 1
- Line from 2 to 6
- Line from 3 to 5
- Point 4

I got **almost** this, it's hard to explain so I'll attach a picture:

### [image: full image]

As you can see, the plane goes through line connecting 4-2 and 5-2 instead of 5-3.

Anybody have an idea how to fix it? I can provide more code if necessary, but I didn't want to put everything and didn't know which part might interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not what I wanted, but I've found a workaround.
I put points in following order (numbers taken from question):

```
1,2,6,6,2,3,5,5,3,4
```

And I set stripCounts filled like this:

```
3,4,3
```

It produces more smaller particles but it's working and after additional work can be generic.

If no better answer appears, I'll accept my own.